# Unable to display items in a List using CoreData SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data, swiftui-list

I'm unable to display items on a list in SwiftuI using CoreData in a new View. I need to display the title and the date selected on a list in another view. It works when I'm displaying it in the same view. However, if I were to get it to show in another view with the same code, it doesn't show anything. I'm not sure if it has something to do with @ObservedObject or something I might've missed or added extra.

This is the View where I select the date and give it a title:

```
struct DatePickerView: View {
    
    //instances of the classes created
    @StateObject var vm = CoreDataViewModel()
    
    @State var titleName : String = ""
    @State var reminderSet : String = ""
    @State var selectedDate : Date = Date()
       
    var dateFormatter : DateFormatter
    {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        return formatter
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                
               Text("Reminders")
                
                DatePicker("Select a Date", selection: $selectedDate, in: Date.now...)
                    .accentColor(Color.red)
                    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                    .frame(width: 320, height: 330)
                
                
                TextField("Enter a title here", text: $titleName)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .frame(height: 40)
                    .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                
                
                Button(action: {
                    guard !titleName.isEmpty else {return}
                    reminderSet = dateFormatter.string(from: selectedDate)
                    vm.addReminders(text: titleName, reminderText: reminderSet)
                    titleName = ""
                    print(titleName)
                    print(reminderSet)
                }, label: {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ReminderListView(vm: CoreDataViewModel())) {
                        Text("Set Reminder")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(height: 40)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.1857388616, blue: 0.5733950138, alpha: 1)))
                            .cornerRadius(10)

                     }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I'm trying to get the List to display:

```
struct ReminderListView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm : CoreDataViewModel
  
    var body: some View {
            
        NavigationView {
            List{
                if !vm.savedEntities.isEmpty{
                    ForEach(vm.savedEntities) { entity in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                Text(entity.title ?? "No Title")
                                Text(entity.dateandtime ?? "No Date and Time Set")
                        }
                    }.onDelete(perform: vm.deleteReminder)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

CoreData Model:

```
class CoreDataViewModel : ObservableObject {
        
    let container : NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var savedEntities: [ReminderEntity] = []
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ReminderContainer")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error loading Core Data : \(error)")
            } else {
                // this else statement can be removed once the core data is loaded successfully.
                print("Successfully loaded Core Data!")
            }
        }
        
        fetchReminders()
    }
    
    func fetchReminders(){
        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<ReminderEntity>(entityName: "ReminderEntity")

        do{
            savedEntities = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch{
            print("Error fetching items from CoreData : \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func addReminders(text : String, reminderText : String) {
        
        let newReminder = ReminderEntity(context: container.viewContext)
        newReminder.title = text
        newReminder.dateandtime = reminderText
        saveData()
    }
    
    func saveData(){
        
        do{
            try container.viewContext.save()
            fetchReminders()
            
        } catch let error{
            print("Error saving data : \(error)")
        }
        
    }
    
    
    // deleting items from CoreData
     func deleteReminder(indexSet : IndexSet){
         
         guard let index = indexSet.first else { return }
         let entity = savedEntities[index]
         container.viewContext.delete(entity)
         saveData()
         
     }
}
```

Comment: Every `ReminderEntity` needs to be wrapped in `@ObservedObhect` also, you aren't observing the store. Instead of creating a view model that holds an `@Published` of CoreData objects you should use `@FetchRequest` at least until you really understand how it all works. A blank SwiftUI/CoreData project will give you the code you need to get started.

Comment: Also, most apps only need 1 `NavigationView` there are very few exceptions to this such as a `sheet` and a `TabView`

Comment: Something else that is Really important every time you call `CoreDataViewModel()` you are creating a different instance, one does not know about the other, stick to only 1.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your comments. I’m fairly new to SwiftUI so I didnt get most of what you said. As I have declared an instance of the ViewModel in the ReminderListView everytime I call that view its aaking me to pass a parameter. What do you suggest I enter in that field to avoid creating a different instance?

Comment: Use the value of the state object

Comment: I have done that. I didnt understand the first comment about ReminderEntity